# Buying Unpasteurized Egg Whites

Tags: egg-whites

I'm in Canada and I see pasteurized cartons of egg whites everywhere, but has anyone seen unpasteurized egg whites? I want to make meringues but I don't want to have to figure out what to do with the yolks.

Or, does cream of tartar + pasteurized egg whites whip like unpasteurized egg whites?

(Specifically I want to try making macarons this time around)

Comment: [This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45232/can-i-make-meringues-with-commercial-egg-whites) has somewhat of an answer to your secondary question about whether pasteurized egg whites will work. Kind of a “your mileage may vary” situation.

Comment: I recall there being something on either America’s Test Kitchen or Milk Street that was some French muffin-like item that specifically used lots of yolks as it was from a time when egg whites were used in paint.  Unfortunately you risk people complaining about ‘poll questions’ if you ask about ways to use up lots of yolks even though ways to use up waste is specifically allowed in the FAQ.  (Or at least, it was)

Comment: @Joe you just need to make a 1024-yolk batch of fresh pasta

Answer (score 3):

In the US, at least, [all egg products must be pasteurized](https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/Are-all-egg-products-pasteurized)

> The term “egg products” refers to eggs that have been removed from their shells for processing at facilities called breaker plants. Egg products include whole eggs, whites, yolks and various blends with or without non-egg ingredients. They may be available in liquid, frozen, and dried forms (eggs inside their shell are NOT egg products.)

It would seem to be the same in [Canada](https://inspection.canada.ca/preventive-controls/eggs-and-processes-egg-products/eng/1524259297433/1524259297745) though that link is less explicit about the requirement. As such, I don’t think you’ll be able to find unpasteurized egg whites legally sold commercially.

As stated in an answer to the [question I linked in a comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45232/can-i-make-meringues-with-commercial-egg-whites):

> With a lot of whipping (and more cream of tartar or other stabilizers) pasteurized egg whites (whether from pasteurized eggs or from cartons) can make meringue though it most likely won't be as stiff as those from non-pasteurized eggs

But as [this answer to a different question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/94537) mentions, it can make life more difficult than unpasteurized egg whites due to the nature of how egg foams work & pasteurization works.

---

TL;DR

You are unlikely to be able to buy unpasteurized egg whites, and for best results will want to crack your own eggs, even if it means you have to figure out something to do with the yolks ([pasta](https://www.today.com/today/amp/rcna72912), perhaps?), but you *should* be able to get by with a bit of extra care and effort using pasteurized egg whites.

Comment: Things to make with lots of egg yolks: sabayon, mayonnaise, caesar dressing, portuguese egg tarts, ice cream, various kinds of custard, creme brulee, extra-rich pasta carbonara, egg breads.  Or make your own tempera paint!